# Clicking on form label focuses the wrong input box

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form that contains two input boxes for first and last name.

When I click the "Last Name" label, the cursor focuses on the "First Name" field (instead of the "Last Name" field as expected). How do I fix this problem?

```js
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
  $('div.tabClass').addClass('hide');
  $($(this).attr('href')).removeClass('hide');
} );
```

```css
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action='' method='POST'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href='#first'>
        First Tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#secound'>
        Second Tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#third'>
        third Tab
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href='#fourth'>
        Fourth Tab
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id='first' class='hide tabClass'>
    <label>
      First Name :
      <input type='text' name='name' id='name'>
      <br/>
      <label>
        Last Name :
        <input type="text" name='sname' id="sname">
        <input type="submit" value="Click">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Almost there. Remove the nonsense at the end. Format all your code. and when saying "i" in English, it has to be capitalized to "I".

Comment: @Affan we are not a code writing service or Yet Another Forum where you can drop in anything and expect it to be solved. We are a site that lives up to high quality standards as can be learned in the [help]. If you want our help, please respect our code of conduct.

Comment: @Affan we don't give out codes for others. We provide answers to questions programmers might need help with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to associate the labels with the input fields.

```
<label for="name">
    First Name :
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
</label>

<label for="sname">
    Last Name  :
    <input type="text" name="sname" id="sname">
</label>
```

As @Sumurai8 mentioned in the comments, the [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element requires a closing tag, which is missing from your code.